How to only select regular list item and not task list item?
To select only listItem, I use:
import {fromMarkdown} from 'mdast-util-from-markdown'
import {inspect} from 'unist-util-inspect'
import {selectAll} from 'unist-util-select'
import {gfm} from 'micromark-extension-gfm'
import {gfmFromMarkdown, gfmToMarkdown} from 'mdast-util-gfm'

const doc = `
## List 
- One
- Two 
## Tasklist
* [ ] to do
* [x] done
`
const tree = fromMarkdown(doc, {
  extensions: [gfm()],
  mdastExtensions: [gfmFromMarkdown()]
})

const listItems = selectAll("listItem", tree)
console.log(inspect(listItems))

The output:
├─0 listItem[1] (3:1-3:6, 10-15)
│   │ spread: false
│   │ checked: null
│   └─0 paragraph[1] (3:3-3:6, 12-15)
│       └─0 text "One" (3:3-3:6, 12-15)
├─1 listItem[1] (4:1-4:7, 16-22)
│   │ spread: false
│   │ checked: null
│   └─0 paragraph[1] (4:3-4:7, 18-22)
│       └─0 text "Two" (4:3-4:6, 18-21)
├─2 listItem[1] (6:1-6:12, 35-46)
│   │ spread: false
│   │ checked: false
│   └─0 paragraph[1] (6:7-6:12, 41-46)
│       └─0 text "to do" (6:7-6:12, 41-46)
└─3 listItem[1] (7:1-7:11, 47-57)
    │ spread: false
    │ checked: true
    └─0 paragraph[1] (7:7-7:11, 53-57)
        └─0 text "done" (7:7-7:11, 53-57)

I notice that task list items have boolean checked, while regular list items have null checked. So to select only task list items, I can use:
const taskItems = selectAll("[checked]", tree)

But how can I only select regular list item? Either of these doesn't work:
const regularItems = selectAll("[checked=null]", tree)  // [] 
const regularItems = selectAll(":not([checked])", tree) // select all nodes
const regularItems = filter(listItems, node => node.checked === null) // undefined
const regularItems = filter(listItems, node => node.checked !== true && node.checked !== false) //undefined

I know I can work on the text, but that's cumbersome and defeats the purpose of the AST.

what does console.log(node) log? probably you can filter on more properties than just type

Check my update. Do you mean that there is no intrinsic way to get the checklist only? As for filter, do you know why unist-util-filter filters only with inequality but not equality?

starts with [x] or [ ] or [-] . You can search if string start with these 3 pattern its tasklist

@Prashant do you know why they don't have different type?

Not sure, this might be a package specific bug, You can check with different library.

Do you have any suggestion?
